# c++ constructor from base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

Is it back practice or some other kind of evil software design to implement a constructor for a derived class getting a base class object? 
I am needing it in the following Vector/Matrix Framework. I want to define the code for the Matrix/Vector multiplication only once - in the Matrix class (in operator*). But within the Matrix class I can only return the abstract base class type:

```
// Base
template<class Value_T, unsigned int N>
class VectorT
{
    ...
};

// Derived
class Vector4 : public VectorT<double, 4>
{
public:
    ...
    Vector4(const VectorT<double, 4>& base);    // base class constructor   
    ...
};

// multiplication operator in a matrix class using the abstract VectorT base type
VectorT<value_type, N> operator*(const VectorT<value_type, N>& v) const
{
    VectorT<value_type, N> vRes;
    ...
    return vRes;    // return by value
}

// usage
Vector4 v;
Matrix4 m;

VectorT<double, 4> vMult = m * v;   // this works but is not what I want

Vector4 vMult = m * v;              // this is what I want, but only works with the base class constructor of Vector4
```

My main goal is to reuse the code of Matrix/Vector multiplication and therefor define it in the matrix class for all possible template specifications of the Matrix- and Vector classes.

Comment: If `Vector4` doesn't do anything beyond `VectorT`, just use a typedef: `typedef VectorT<double, 4> Vector4;` (Or type alias in C++11: `using Vector4 = VectorT<double, 4>;`)

Comment: Not related to your question, but are your matrices always NxN? If not, you should use `VectorT<value_type, M> operator*(const VectorT<value_type, N>& v);` instead

Comment: Thx for the hint, a typedef is a straight forward solution, but actually my Vector4 class has some specific behaviour.

Comment: @Erbureth: Yes, I only need quadratic matrice and therefor they are all NxN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a base class object in the constructor of a derived class object is a perfectly valid approach. Think of that as *Copy constructor for base class portion and default constructor for derived class portion*.

Answer (score 2):

As T.C. pointed out in the comment, you don't even need to have the derived class to use a `Vector4` type.

Here's a 3x3 times 3 example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Value_T, unsigned int N>
struct VectorT
{
  VectorT() : data() { }
  Value_T data[N];
};

typedef VectorT<double, 3> Vector_d3;

template < class Value_T, unsigned int N, unsigned int M >
struct MatrixT : VectorT<VectorT<Value_T, M>, N>
{
  VectorT<Value_T, N> operator* (VectorT<Value_T, M> const & v)
  {
    VectorT<Value_T, N> result;
    for (size_t i(0); i < M; ++i)
    {
      for (size_t j(0); j < N; ++j) result.data[i] += data[i].data[j] * v.data[j];
    }
    return result;
  }
};

typedef MatrixT<double, 3, 3> Matrix_d33;

int main()
{
  /*
    m =
    1 2 3 
    4 5 6
    7 8 9
  */
  Matrix_d33 m;
  m.data[0].data[0] = 1;
  m.data[0].data[1] = 2;
  m.data[0].data[2] = 3;
  m.data[1].data[0] = 4;
  m.data[1].data[1] = 5;
  m.data[1].data[2] = 6;
  m.data[2].data[0] = 7;
  m.data[2].data[1] = 8;
  m.data[2].data[2] = 9;
  /*
    v =
    5 4 3
  */
  Vector_d3 v;
  v.data[0] = 5;
  v.data[1] = 4;
  v.data[2] = 3;
  /*
  res =
  1*5 + 2*4 + 3*3 = 22
  4*5 + 5*4 + 6*3 = 58
  7*5 + 8*4 + 9*3 = 94
  */
  Vector_d3 res = m*v;

  std::cout << res.data[0] << std::endl;
  std::cout << res.data[1] << std::endl;
  std::cout << res.data[2] << std::endl;

}
```

The code prints:

```
22
58 
94
```