# Convert from a Base object to a Derived object in C++

Tags: c++, windows, oop, directx

I am trying to abstract sections of code to be platform independent.

I have one section of code that is creating objects of Base class `IModel`.

```
std::shared_ptr<IModel> joint_model_3d = std::make_shared<IModel>();
```

I have another section of code that is responsible for rendering. In order to render the object I need to convert it to the derived class `Direct3DModel`

```
class Direct3DModel : public IModel
```

I know that I can do a `dynamic_cast` from `Direct3DModel` to `IModel` for sections of code that are platform independent, and then `dynamic_cast` back into `Direct3DModel` for rendering.

My question is, can I create an object of the Base class `IModel` in the platform independent code, which is not supposed to know `Direct3DModel`, and convert it to `Direct3DModel` when I need it for rendering.

Would I need some kind of object creator class that is not platform independent for this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)

Comment: You could have a constructor for Derived that takes a Base.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/24166819/1216776

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, can I create an object of the Base class `IModel` in the platform independent code, which is not supposed to know `Direct3DModel`, and convert it to `Direct3DModel` when I need it for rendering.

No, that won't work.

You'll have to create a `Direct3DModel` object in the code base that knows about the class. The platform independent code needs to call the platform dependent code to construct such an object. You may use the [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) to implement the functionality.

The platform independent code will have to work with base class pointers and references (`IModel` in your case). As long as the pointer/reference points to a `Direct3DModel` object, you may use `dynamic_cast` in the platform-specific code to get a pointer/reference to the `Direct3DModel` to proceed with the platform-specific logic.

> Would I need some kind of object creator class that is not platform independent for this?

Yes. The Factory Pattern facilitates that.